# My website does not work on firefox

Tags: javascript, css, html, firefox

So I've made a website for my internship assignment (first year of my study hence the lack of experience). Sadly I've ran into the problem where it works on every browser except firefox. The problem with firefox is that nothing works. none of the menus links anything really. ****

I was wondering if anyone here could help me solve the problem after countless hours of trying to fix it myself.

So I am using Html,css and some javascript for the website posted below.

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="tartufi.css" media="screen"/>
<title>xxxxxx</title>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Karla:700' rel='stylesheet'      type='text/css'/>
</head>

<body>
<p>&nbsp;</p>

 <div class="header"> 

    </div>

<div class="alpha">
      <div class="headermenu"> 


            <div class="logo">

            </div> 

        <nav>
        <ul id="navigation">
            <li><div class="navSection "><a id="nav1" href="">HOME</a> </div></li>
            <li><div class="navSection "><a id="nav2" href="">PASSION</a> </div></li>
            <li><div class="navSection "><a id="nav3" href="">CONTACT</a> </div></li>
        </ul>
        </nav>
        <div class="talen">
          <a href="index.html"><img style="border:0;" src="nederlands.png" alt="English" /></a>
          <a href="index_en.html"><img style="border:0;" src="english.png" alt="English" /></a>
          <a href="index_du.html"><img style="border:0;" src="deutsch.png" alt="Deutsch" /></a>
        </div>
    </div>

  <div class="content"> 

    <article class="content">

    <section id="s1"> 
        <div id="services" class="f"> 
        </div>
    </section>

    <section id="s2">
        <div id="services2" class="b"> 

         <div class="tekstcontent">


         </div>

             <div class="imagecontent">
             </div>

        </div>
    </section>


    <section id="s3">
        <div id="services3" class="c"> 

        <div class="contact">
        person lastname <br/>
        street<br/>
        postal code<br/><br/>

        <img src="streep.png" alt="" /><br/><br/>
        <img src="tel.png" alt=""/>
       phone <br/><br/>
        <img src="fax.png" alt="" >
        fax<br/><br/>
        <img src="email.png" alt="" align="center">
        <a href="mailto:xxxx@xxxxxxxx" class="contactlink">xxxx@xxxxxxxx</a>
        </div>

            <div class="imagecontent">
            </div>


        </div>
    </section>
    </article>
  </div>

    <div class="footer">
    Copyright © 2014.
<a  href="http://www.xxxxx.xxxx/" target="_blank" style="color:grey;">xxxx xxxx xxxxxx</a>
</div>
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

my css

```
body {

    background-color: black;
    background-image:url("background.jpeg");
    background-size: 1300px 768px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position: top;


}

.alpha {

    width: 1300px;
    height: 768px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: -55px;
    position:relative;

    }

.header {

    width: 100.9% ;
    margin-left: -5px;

    height: 100px;
    margin-top: -55px;
    background-color:white;
    opacity: 0.4;
    float: left;
    }

.headermenu {

    width: 1300px;
    height: 120px;

    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    position: absolute;



    }

.logo {

    width:263px;
    height:350px;
    position:relative;
    background-image:url("LOGO.png");
    background-size:100%;
    color:green;
    float:left;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    }

.imagecontent {

    width:1300px;
    height:648px;
    position:relative;
    background-image:url("bgcontent.png");
    margin-left: 600px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;

    }


.tekstcontent {

    width:435px;
    height:120px;
    position:relative;
    background-color:#D6D6D6;
    float:left;
    margin-left: 263px;
    margin-top: 120px;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color:black;
     padding-top: 25px;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
    padding-right: 50px;
    padding-left: 20px;

    }

.contact {

    width:400px;
    height:400px;
    font-family:Candara;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    margin-left: 320px;
    margin-top: 70px;
    z-index:2;
    padding: 10px ;
    font-size: 30px ;
    text-align: middle;
    }




.content {

    width:1300px;
    height:648px;
    overflow: hidden;

    }

.f      {

    Width:1300px;
    height:648px;

    opacity:0;
    }

.b  {

    Width:1300px;
    height: 648px;
    background-color: white;

    }

.c      {

    Width:1300px;
    height: 648px;
    background-color: white;
    }

.talen  {
    height:120px;
    width:300px;
    padding-left: 70px;

    float:left;
    }

.footer {
     width:1300px;
     height:23px;
     background-color:#000000;
     color:grey;
     text-align:center;
    }



/*nav*/



ul#navigation {
        list-style:none;
        position:relative;
        top:-15px;
        }
    ul#navigation li {
        float:left;
        margin-left:20px;
        margin-right:-20px;
        }
    ul#navigation li a {


        display:block;
        padding:30.5px 30px;
        text-decoration:none;
        color:black;
        font-size: 33px;
        margin-left:10px;
    font-family: 'Karla', sans-serif;
        font
        }

    ul#navigation li a:hover{
        background-color: #c62126;

        }   


/* page styles */

a {
    color: red;
}
```

and my js

```
// kadaj Oct 2012

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.navSection').on('click', function (e) {
        debugger;
        var elemId = "";    //eg: #nav2
        switch (e.target.id) {
        case "nav1":
            elemId = "#s1";
            break;
        case "nav2":
            elemId = "#s2";
            break;
        case "nav3":
            elemId = "#s3";
            break;
        case "nav4":
            elemId = "#s4";
            break;
        }
        $('.content').animate({
            scrollTop: $(elemId).parent().scrollTop() + $(elemId).offset().top - $(elemId).parent().offset().top
        }, {
            duration: 1000,
            specialEasing: {
                width: 'linear',
                height: 'easeOutBounce'
            },
            complete: function (e) {
                //console.log("animation completed");
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Any help is extremely appreciated

Comment: What does it show in the console?

Comment: This is a very vague question, try narrowing down the problem please before you post it, we are not freelancers who want to invest 7 hours in resolving a problem for you. A fiddle could help a lot too.

Comment: x-site scripting. I had the same problem with FF. You are importing jQuery via CDN (src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"), for some reason FF doesn't like it (maybe it can be changed in FF settings, don't know). If you download jQuery to your local machine/server where you host the page, and include it in your page this way, it should work.

Comment: @DanielGruszczyk It works fine on my Firefox ver31.0.

Comment: @DanielGruszczyk I've added the jQuery to my server and changed the code but it didn't seem to work.

Comment: @Rsauxil I added a link to the website for people to try it in firefox to see what i mean.

Comment: @Rsauxil the link is not enough. Tell us **exactly** what is not working: what result you except and what result you get, what do you see in your console (Firebug for example). We don't event know if it's a CSS problem or a JavaScript problem...

Comment: @pomeh Well that's the problem I don't know if it's a html,css or js problem either. And I really don't know how to describe the problem cause. Everything works in chrome,opera,IE,safari But absolutely nothing works in firefox.

Comment: So you are saying it is to us to search the problem in your approximately 300 lines of code? For me: No thanks in helping you out. Do some investigation first.

Comment: **nohting** works, what does it means ? Describe what you see: a blank page ? no text content ? And describe what you want. Maybe add a screenshot for Chrome and Firefox for ! You have to be as specific as possible for us to help, if you're not your question will be closed and you won't have any response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `<div class="header"></div>` is in front of your div with navigation, and thus you can't click anything inside of your navigation div.
Add in css to your .headermenu:

```
.headermenu{
    //what you had before
    z-index: 999;
}
```

Higher z-index will bring any elements with it (or within element with that z-index) in front of anything else with lower z-index (I think default is 1).

Comment: This solved my problem! many thanks! And thank you for the explenation why. I will keep it in mind for the future!

Answer (score 0):

As per the current code, put the below code at the end of your CSS file. It will work in firefox. Tested using Fiddler.

```
#navigation
{
    z-index: 1000;
}
```